# How likely are polished concrete, decorative concrete overlay, or epoxy flooring to delaminate if our house floods?

Tags: concrete, flooring, self-leveling-concrete, epoxy

Our house recently flooded and my wife and I are looking at different flooring options. We are considering concrete flooring but I have some questions about how likely each are to stand up to a new flood.

Our house historically has never flooded and this is the first time, but I want to have a peace of mind that if it does happen again I will have the least amount of worry.

From what I've seen it seems like polished concrete has little to no risk of delamination, stained concrete overlay seems to have contradictory information, and epoxy seems to be similarly prone to flood damage like linoleum might be.

How likely are these to delaminate in flooding? I'm not talking about a toilet that overflows but rather natural disaster. Our house is slab concrete and had about 2 feet of water for between 36 and 48 hours.

Comment: Epoxy is used on the inside of tanks containing water, food, and chemicals... so I doubt it's going to have a big problem with flood waters.

Comment: I would agree with epoxy and polished concrete is almost as tough. depending on the type of overlay this may not be a good idea inside because flood water contains sewage much of the time and some overlays are not as tight and may be really tough to clean after a flood.

Comment: Why not use a regular flooring and just consider it disposable? Cleaning a permanent flooring might turn out more expensive than replacing it outright.

Comment: polished concrete is polished.  Nothing but concrete that is polished. nothing to peal off if nothing is there. Perhaps you will need to re-polish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a concrete floor, have that stripped, polished and stained. It will stay even if the house goes away.

An overlay that is well bonded to the existing floor will hang in there pretty tough too, but the floor will need to be stripped down to bare as well.